# Draw at least 2 of the same card, and 1 of another card

Tags: probability, card-games

I'm trying to work out some statistics for a game I'm working on, but can't wrap my head around some of the statistical concepts.

To make a generic case along the lines of what I'm trying to do:

Let's take a standard deck of 52 cards. What is the probability that, if I draw 7 cards, at least 3 of them are hearts, and at least 2 of them are different non-heart faces (i.e. they can't both be kings, or both be queens, etc.)?

It's not a perfect analog for what I'm actually doing, but it's close enough.

Comment: I am sorry but I think you would have to break into cases and add them up...

Comment: You can also calculate the complements, e.g. subtract drawings with 0,1,2 hearts from all drawings.

Answer (score 0):

I think I've come up with an answer, can somebody confirm if this is correct?

3 hearts = 13 × 12 × 11

First non-heart face = 9

Second non-heart face = 6

All criteria together = 13 × 12 × 11 × 9 × 6